# Graphql with nested mutations?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to figure out how to mutate a nested object with graphql mutations, if possible. For instance I have the following schema:

```
type Event {
    id: String
    name: String
    description: String
    place: Place
}

type Place {
    id: String
    name: String
    location: Location
}

type Location {
    city: String
    country: String
    zip: String
}

type Query {
    events: [Event]
}

type Mutation {
    updateEvent(id: String, name: String, description: String): Event
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

How can I add the place information inside my `updateEvent` mutation?

Comment: This might serve as inspiration: https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/nested-create-mutations-vaet3eengo/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add a whole object to the mutation you have to define a graphql element of the type input. Here is a link to a small [cheatsheet](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet).

In your case it could look like this:

```js
    type Location {
        city: String
        country: String
        zip: String
    }

    type Place {
        id: String
        name: String
        location: Location
    }

    type Event {
        id: String
        name: String
        description: String
        place: Place
    }

    input LocationInput {
       city: String
       country: String
       zip: String
    }

    input PlaceInput {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        location: LocationInput!
    }

    type Query {
        events: [Event]
    }

    type Mutation {
        updateEvent(id: String, name: String, description: String, place: PlaceInput!): Event
    }

    schema {
        query: Query
        mutation: Mutation
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid providing all the nested fields? For example if I don't provide the full location object, the fields which I don't provide are replaced with null or removed. Any idea about it?

Comment: You could remove the "!" from the input type then it is not required anymore. Doing so you could use just a part of the location object. I think in the resolver function it will be undefined. But i'm not sure about that.

Comment: This should not work. [GraphQL.org](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types) says that `The fields on an input object type can themselves refer to input object types, but you can't mix input and output types in your schema.` You would need an extra `LocationInput` type.

Answer (score 16):

Generally speaking, you should avoid thinking of the arguments to your mutations as a direct mapping to object types in your schema. Whilst it's true that they will often be similar, you're better off approaching things under the assumption that they won't be.

Using your basic types as an example. Let's say I wanted to create a new event, but rather than knowing the location, I just have the longitude/latitude - it's actually the backend that calculates the real location object from this data, and I certainly don't know its ID (it doesn't have one yet!). I'd probably construct my mutation like this:

```
input Point {
  longitude: Float!
  latitude: Float!
}

input PlaceInput {
  name
  coordinates: Point!
}

type mutation {
  createEvent(
    name: String!
    description: String
    placeId: ID
    newPlace: PlaceInput
  ): Event  
  updateEvent(
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    placeId: ID
    newPlace: PlaceInput
  ): Event
)
```

A mutation is basically just a function call, and it's best to think of it in those terms. If you wrote a function to create an Event, you likely wouldn't provide it an event and expect it to return an event, you'd provide the *information necessary to create an Event*.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question as the OP - what would the usage of `createEvent()` look like in this case, as PlaceInput is still a complex type?

Comment: Can you add a sample resolver function too that consumes the newPlace and how it access the manipulated the data, a sample insert

Comment: @andymccullough I realize it's been three years, but for completeness: `mutation { createEvent(name: "Foo", newPlace: {name: "Somewhere", coordinates: {longitude: 42, latitude: 42}})`