# Apollo Graphql mutation with dynamic number of email address

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, graphql-tag

I have successfully created a graphql mutation that allows me to create a Staff record.

```
mutation addNewStaff {
  createStaff(input: {
    first_name: "Test Name"
    last_name: "Lname"
    nickname: "Nname"
    positionId: 10
    divisionId: 6
    contact_numbers: [
      {number: "66643535"}
      {number: "876876867"}
    ]
    emails: [
      {address: "testuser@gmail.com"}
      {address: "gfdsaasd@gmail.com"}
    ]
    office_location: "OP" 
  }) {
    id
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
```

the result is

```
{
  "data": {
    "createStaff": {
      "id": "16",
      "first_name": "Test Name",
      "last_name": "Lname"
    }
  }
}
```

the emails and contact_numbers are dynamic fields meaning a Staff can have unlimited number of emails and contact numbers(these are stored in a separate database tables with foreign key to the staff table). I am now writing the frontend code for this project using react and apollo client. I am very confused on how to write the gql code for creating a mutation. I cant find a good example on what I am trying to accomplish. Can someone guide me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphql with nested mutations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670733/graphql-with-nested-mutations)

Comment: No my concern is different. I already implemented the mutation in the server side. The code above works on graphiql. I want to know now how to do it on the client side using apollo / gql.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different variables for your mutation, for example:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const addNewStaffMutation = gql`
  mutation addNewStaff(
    $firstName: Sting!, 
    $lastName: String!,
    ...
    $positionId: number!, 
    $divisionId: number!, 
    ...
  ) {
  createStaff(input: {
    first_name: $firstName
    last_name: $lastName
    nickname: "Nname"
    positionId: $positionId
    divisionId: $divisionId
    contact_numbers: [
      {number: "66643535"}
      {number: "876876867"}
    ]
    emails: [
      {address: "testuser@gmail.com"}
      {address: "gfdsaasd@gmail.com"}
    ]
    office_location: "OP" 
  }) {
    id
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
`
```

> I've only replaced some of your arguments for the example, as your payload is quite big.

Then you can just build your `react` component and pass all the variables. You can read more about it and see some examples on [Apollo Mutations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html).